# Sending Informations to thermal printer via c#

Tags: c#, printing, thermal-printer

Hello everyone reading this! I'm working with a GPT-4672-PM-C32 Thermalprinter, which my boss wants me to get to work via .Net. The company has provided me with some source code which contains a few DLL files which we want to avoid using, since the application might not be only used on windows 10. I've tried the following code from a different topic on here to no prevail:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
public class RawPrinterHelper
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] Array = ConvertToByteArray("Druck mich bitte bitte Ich hab keine Lust nicht gedruckt zu werden!\n", Encoding.ASCII);
        string stuff = Formatio(Array);
        byte[] Binary = ConvertToByteArray(stuff, Encoding.ASCII);
        IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Binary.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(Binary, 0, unmanagedPointer, Binary.Length);
        // Call unmanaged code
        Int32 Counter = Binary.Length;
        /*
        if(SendBytesToPrinter("MyPrinter",unmanagedPointer, Counter) != false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HOORAY!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BOOOOH");
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
        */
    
    }
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.

    public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(string str, Encoding encoding)
    {
        return encoding.GetBytes(str);
    }
    //Formats a byte[] into a binary string (010010010010100101010)
    public static string Formatio(byte[] data)
    {
        //storage for the resulting string
        string result = string.Empty;
        //iterate through the byte[]
        foreach (byte value in data)
        {
            //storage for the individual byte
            string binarybyte = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
            //if the binarybyte is not 8 characters long, its not a proper result
            while (binarybyte.Length < 8)
            {
                //prepend the value with a 0
                binarybyte = "0" + binarybyte;
            }
            //append the binarybyte to the result
            result += binarybyte;
        }
        //return the result
        return result;
    }
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;

        // How many characters are in the string?
        // Fix from Nicholas Piasecki:
        // dwCount = szString.Length;
        dwCount = (szString.Length + 1) * Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize;

        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The function creates a printjob which isn't passed to the printer. The printer also communicates via its own set of ESC commands, which also need to be sent to the printer. Considering that the demo code from the company who designed this device simply sends strings and ESC commands as unmanaged byte data, I'm running out of ideas on how to communicate with this printer. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: _"Considering that the demo code from the company who designed this device simply sends strings and ESC commands as unmanaged byte data, I'm running out of ideas on how to communicate with this printer."_ - sounds like all you need to do is to follow the printer's communication protocol specs and send bytes to the serial (?) interface? Which is basically a high level driver ...

Comment: @Fildor This is what I'm trying to replicate, yes. And to the serial connection: I'm not sure if there is one. The printer is communicated to via USB, the demo doesn't select a COM port, but rather the USB device. It is shown as "USB0" in the software. That got me confused aswell. Maybe it's just this manufacturer's specific device thats so tricky. I've seen other devices, EPSON or Zebra, which have a way easier way of communication, but no, I get this.

Comment: Well, today, there are not really "serial" devices any more. Everything is USB (with exceptions). But: Many device manufacturers do not directly implement USB drivers, but use "Serial Port Emulation". Which makes it pretty easy to interface, because you just open the port and read / write. Now what you wrote in the comment seems to indicate that this manufacturer indeed _did_ implement a USB driver. The question would then be a) if there is _also_ a "Serial Port Emulation" Mode and/or b) how do they interface on Linux?

Comment: @Fildor There is an emulation mode, the printer supports RS232. The manual however mentions that if both USB and RS232 are connected, only USB is being used. Also, another thing I want to mention: The printer isn't listed as a printer under windows, but rather under "other devices", and it doesn't have a real name, it's just listed as "USB Printer". And they offer their own driver for Linux.

Comment: @Fildor I just solved it. The driver the printer came with was the issue. Removing it and re-installing it as "generic/text only" Allowed me to print the basic printer test page via Windows. This means that the remaining code should be functional if executed correctly. Thanks a bunch tho.